# Displaying related documents in Meteor with only the id

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze

I think this question is different from the ones already on here. I've been struggling with this and can't find a good solution.

Assume something like this:

```
//ResourceOne { name: "foobar" } ... ResourceTwo { name: "donuts" }
Resources = new Meteor.Collection('resources');

//{ input: ResourceOneID, output: ResourceTwoID }
Connections = new Meteor.Collection('connections');
```

Connections connect Resources to other Resources, storing only their `_id`s.

I want to display a list of Connections in the form

```
foobar --> donuts
```

How in the world do I do that?

Right now I have:

```
{{#each connections}}
    <a href="#">{{ input_name }} --> {{ output_name }}</a>
{{/each}}
```

Which is powered by the template helper:

```
input_name: function() {
    return Resources.find( { _id: this.input } ).fetch()[0].name;
}
```

**This works**, but fails whenever the page is not completely refreshed.

What's a better way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably because you're not waiting for the data to fully arrive. When you run this

```
Resources.find( { _id: this.input } ).fetch()[0].name;
```

You're assuming that `Resoureces.find(..).fetch()[0]` has a result, but this will not always be the case. When your page loads initially data may not have yet arrived on the browser and the result would be `null`. If you check the `name` attribute it would then throw an exception.

You just need to handle this case for it to work:

```
var resource = Resources.findOne( { _id: this.input } );
return resource && resource.name;
```

Note: `findOne()` is the same as `.fetch()[0]`.

So here `resource` returns `null` if its null and won't check its `name` attribute.

Comment: THAT FEELS LIKE MAGIC. Thanks so much! Do you mind if I ask: I understand the idiom in the return statement, but what causes the system to 'wait' for resource.name to have a value? I.e., how do we know `resource.name` will not be null when it's returned?

Comment: BTW I tried voting up but I don't have enough reputation points yet...let me know if there's any other way I can compensate. This had me stumped for a WHILE.

Comment: @m52go No worries. It doesn't really wait. Initially it returns "" (nothing) & as soon as the data arrives it fills it up, since its reactive it adjusts to the new data without any more code